# Does try with resources work if a thread is terminated abruptly with System.exit()?

Tags: java, multithreading, try-with-resources

I have a multithreaded application where each thread opens a stream on a URL and reads lines from it. However, the entire program may be terminated at any time with System.exit(). If I open the stream with try-with-resources, will the stream be closed on exit?

Comment: The stream won't be closed in Java, but I'd expect the OS resources to be cleaned up, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html: "If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute."